# Davening Riddle

Tags: calendar, eretz-yisrael, chutz-laaretz, maariv, riddle

With variations in the jewish calendar, how is it possible to daven maariv on nine consecutive nights and every shemoneh esrei is different from the other eight?

Example: Thurs nite is a weekday, friday night is shmone esre of shabbos, motzei shabbos has ata chonantonu

Comment: Closed, per our policy on riddles http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/140/759

Comment: I added the tag "riddle" because the question is a riddle. But the tag description reads, "NOTE: This tag is for historical interest only; do not use. Riddles are discouraged as questions on StackExchange. Any riddle questions posted here are likely to be closed."

Comment: If 30 Kislev is 4 December on Tuesday. Then 
F Shabbat Chanuka S Chanukah + Attah S Reg Chanuka M Chanukah + Rosh Chodesh T Chanukha + Rosh Chodesh + Tal Umatar W Chanukah + Tal Umatar R Tal Umatar F Reg Shabbat S Tal Umattar + Attah. This last happened in 1956 and before that in 1888. The next time will be in 2108, but by then Tal Umatar will have drifted to Dec 5.