# Different Maariv 9 days in a row

Tags: chanuka, maariv

Under what circumstances can you have 9 days in a row with no two Maarivs being exactly the same as each other? Related to Chanuka

Comment: If they fall out during sefirah.

Comment: Is this a riddle?

Comment: @shmosel That's a great answer. There's also one related to Chanuka (question has been edited to reflect that)

Comment: @rosends I guess you can call it that, but it's not a trick question in any way and there is a real answer

Comment: Duplicate: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/68383/4940